# chart-studio plotly not working in jupyter notebook

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, anaconda, plotly

I am using the below piece of code in jupyter notebbok on a conda python environment

```
import chart_studio.plotly as plt
fig, axes = plt.subplots(1, 3, figsize=(15, 5), sharey=False)
```

I keep running into this error though and not sure how to solve this

```
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-8-5515d0d73775> in <module>
----> 1 fig, axes = plt.subplots(1, 3, figsize=(15, 5), sharey=False)

AttributeError: module 'chart_studio.plotly' has no attribute 'subplots'
```

I have tried uninstalling and reinstalling the chart-studio package.
I currently have these versions of the packages

- chart-studio-1.1.0
- plotly-5.6.0

Appreciate the help.

Comment: You'll have to use `from plotly.subplots import make_subplots`